# Highlight the differences in columns across worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am trying to compare three different columns of data in three worksheets and highlight the differences using VBA. I am very new to VBA and I don't know a lot about programming. So far this is what I've done:

`worksheet1`:

```
Sub compare_cols()
 Dim myRng As Range
 Dim lastCell As Long
 'Get the last row
 Dim lastRow As Integer
 lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
 'Debug.Print "Last Row is " & lastRow
 Dim c As Range
 Dim d As Range
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 For Each c In Worksheets("worksheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
 For Each d In Worksheets("worksheet2").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
 c.Interior.Color = vbGreen
 If (InStr(1, d, c, 1) > 0) Then
 c.Interior.Color = vbWhite
 Exit For
 End If
 Next
 Next
 For Each c In Worksheets("worksheet2").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
 For Each d In Worksheets("worksheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
 c.Interior.Color = vbYellow
 If (InStr(1, d, c, 1) > 0) Then
 c.Interior.Color = vbWhite
 Exit For
 End If
 Next
 Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
End Sub
Worksheet 2:
Sub compare_cols()
 Dim myRng As Range
 Dim lastCell As Long
 'Get the last row
 Dim lastRow As Integer
 lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
 'Debug.Print "Last Row is " & lastRow
 Dim c As Range
 Dim d As Range
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 For Each c In Worksheets("worksheet2").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
 For Each d In Worksheets("worksheet3").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
 c.Font.Color = rgbRed
 If (InStr(1, d, c, 1) > 0) Then
 c.Font.Color = rgbBlack
 Exit For
 End If
 Next
 Next
 For Each c In Worksheets("worksheet3").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
 For Each d In Worksheets("worksheet2").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Cells
 c.Interior.Color = vbRed
 c.Font.Color = rgbWhite
 If (InStr(1, d, c, 1) > 0) Then
 c.Interior.Color = vbWhite
 c.Font.Color = rgbBlack
 Exit For
 End If
 Next
 Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
End Sub
```

**Problems I'm having:**

- in comparing `worksheet1` and `worksheet2`, data that is not in `worksheet2` are highlighted green in `worksheet1`, and data that is not in `worksheet1` are highlighted yellow in `worksheet2`.
- some of the data in `worksheet2` for example are highlighted in yellow but are found in `worksheet1`, which shouldn’t happen. Then in comparing `worksheet2` and `worksheet3`, items that are not in `worksheet3` have a red colored font, in `worksheet2`, and items that are not in `worksheet2` are highlighted red with a white font, in `worksheet3`.
- data in `worksheet2` for example have a red colored font but are found in `worksheet3`, which shouldn’t happen.

Can you please tell me why my VBA code isn't working, or what I else I can do?

Comment: thanks BK201, how did you edit my question the way you did? also do you have any suggestions to my problem???

Comment: Read up on the help section while posting. All the tricks are there. :) Also, there are a couple of tricks that can be employed here. First, though, won't simple conditional formatting work? Have you tried? :)

Comment: I thought you couldn't use conditional formatting for different worksheets in excel 2007?

Comment: well the range of data in each worksheet will vary each time a report is run, I'm working with large spreadsheets, that need to be sent to clients as quickly as possible

Comment: I will go the way @pnuts suggested. You can do dynamic named ranges anyway. This is just a simple `=COUNTIF(...)=0` check, really. :)

Comment: How would I use a countif is the way I need it, im a bit confused. is there not a way to use vba? or is it more difficult?

Comment: It is indeed more difficult, simply because writing the code for this is definitely more cumbersome than just pointing and clicking and a few bits of typing. The question is, does it really need VBA?

Comment: I don't want to have to enter a countif formula every time I have to run a report.

Comment: conditional formatting doesn't seem to do the job

Comment: Conditional formatting is not working for  me, what else can I do?

Comment: Yeah,  that's my first post,  I got this far,  I just need to find the solutions to my problems, the code I use works for the most part,  I just gotta get of the hiccups

Comment: I've provided a solution that does not implement VBA. If your open to it, see my post.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution without VBA:

Suppose you have a data like this:

[image: sample data]

First, create a `Dynamic Named Range` for each like this:

[image: dynamic range]

**This is How you do it:**

1. Go to **FORMULAS** > **NAME MANAGER**
2. Click **NEW**
3. Enter the name of your data (I used Data1, Data2 and Data3 to refer to data in each WS respectively)
4. Use this formula to make your `NAMED RANGE` dynamic.
   **For Data1:** `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1,1)`
   **For Data2:** `=OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!$A:$A)-1,1)`
   **For Data3:** `=OFFSET(Sheet3!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet3!$A:$A)-1,1)`

Read [THIS](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/830287) to further understand how.

**Second, apply** `CONDITIONAL FORMATTING` **like this:**

[image: format]

You will apply this `Conditional Formatting` in your first data in `Sheet1`, `Sheet2` and `Sheet3`.
Then, use the `Format Painter` to copy it on other cells with data.

**Formula for Sheet1 A2:** `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($A2,Data2,0)),1,0)`
Note: This is to highlight data not in SHEET2
Choose the format (you want it to be higlighted GREEN)
**Formula for Sheet2 A2:** (Remember we have 2 formula)
a. `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($A2,Data1,0)),1,0)`
Note: This is to higlight data not in SHEET1 (highlight yellow).
b. `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($A2,Data3,0)),1,0)`
Note: This is to make red font data not in SHEET3
**Formula for Sheet3 A2:** `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($A2,Data2,0)),1,0)`
Note: This is to highlight and change font color to white on data not in SHEET2.

**IMPORTANT:** Do not forget to set the formats! And take note of the `$ signs` on the formulas.

After accomplishing above, here is the result:

[image: result]

Try adding data on each sheet and you will notice that `Conditional Formatting` auto apply.
That's how it is at least in my end.
So no worries when you add new data.
If it doesn't automatically apply, you can simple use the `Format Painter`.
Hope this works for you.

Comment: My friend and I figured it out in VBA, turns out I needed to set a range so instead of range("A2:A"& lastrow) just have it as range("A2:A10000"), when we did that it seemed to work.  Thanks ya all for the suggestions, much appreciated.

Comment: @user3138463 np :) i just propose alternatives but you can always work where you're most comfortable.

Comment: Thank you,  I intend to explore the alternatives you and others propose.  :)